# ask sas to remember sas explorer column size change permanently

Tags: sas

SAS Explorer window allows user to change column size. For eg, set type, size and path to 0 so that modified is all that is displayed.  How do I get SAS to remember this from session to session?  Windows 10 pro 64bit SAS 9.4.m3 64bit.
I have a vague recollection of a command like wdlgsave, but this doesn't do it and doesn't issue an error in the log.

Comment: sas online help for explorer window says

... Table sizes include the number of rows and columns in parenthesis. By default, member details are not displayed and column widths are not remembered. 

1. 
With the Explorer window active, select Toolsthen selectOptionsthen selectExplorer or use the DMEXPOPTS command. 
 

2. 
On the General tab, select Member Details. You can also select Remember Column Widths in the Miscellaneous section. 
 

3. 
Click OK to make your changes effective immediately.

Comment: This does not do what I want. I want it remembered from one sas session to the next.

Comment: `wpgmsave` perhaps?  When you start SAS, do you get a note that session changes will not be saved?

Answer (score 0):

When you're in SAS Explorer, go into `Tools > Options > Explorer > General,` and under `miscellaneous`, select `Remember Column Widths`.